# Entering 3 letters in array with space between it

Tags: c, arrays, char

I need to enter 3 letters or numbers on char array with space between them. I NEED to use scanf since we didn't learn any other method. This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    void main(){

        char lista[3];
        int x;
        printf("Enter 3 letters with space between them : ");
        scanf_s(" %s", lista, sizeof(lista));
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @AntonioGvardijan You need this `scanf_s(" %c %c %c", &lista[0],(rsize_t)1,&lista[1],(rsize_t)1, &lista[2],(rsize_t)1);`

Comment: Posting examples of input and expected output would help.  The details are lacking.  Are all these OK? `"a b c"`, `"a b 10"`,  `"a b (many spaces)   c"`, `"ab c"`, `"a á c"`,  `"a b c d"`?  By some definition, these all meet "3 letters or numbers on char array"

Answer (score 0):

```
char c[3];
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter 3 chars separated by space and press enter :");
    while (count < 3)
    {
        scanf("%c%*[ ]", &c[count]); // *[ ] ignores the empty spaces after each character
        count++;
    }

    printf("c1:%c\n", c[0]);
    printf("c2:%c\n", c[1]);
    printf("c3:%c\n", c[2]);
```